# Fake webcam for Skype on Android

Tags: android, camera, skype

I am building a remote-controlled robot that is powered by an Android tablet, using Skype for the video stream.

I'm using the Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5 SM-T800 that allows the front and rear camera to be used simultaneously. The "Camera" app allows for picture-in-picture photos where both the front and rear cameras are visible. I want to see the front and rear simultaneously via Skype.

Skype only allows one camera to be viewed at a time. On PC it's quite easy to trick Skype into using a fake webcam input provided by another program - is this possible on Android too? In that case, I could create my own app that takes the front and rear cameras simultaneously, creates a picture-in-picture video feed, and present that as a fake camera to Skype.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no